# GET request denied - Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I would like to fetch the JSON data used to plot this chart [here](https://www.oceans14.com.br/acoes/historico-pl-bovespa) using Python's requests library. Inspecting the Network panel via Dev. Tools, I was able to find the URL of the respective GET request ([gHistoricoPIBovespa.aspx?periodo=completo](https://www.oceans14.com.br/rendaVariavel/respostaAjax/gHistoricoPlBovespa.aspx?periodo=completo)). One can visualize the response from within the panel and confirm that this is the correct data. However, if one tries to simply open this link, the server denies the access. It reads:

> Access Denied
>
> Due to daily attempted attacks on the site, we do not allow: Access
> via VPN, multiple simultaneous requests and access from abroad (mainly
> Asia). If you are a legitimate user and not a robot, send an email to
> contato@oceans14.com.br informing your IP address: ***.**.***.**. We
> will get back to you informing you whether your IP address has been
> unblocked or not.

I am not a Web Developer, but I always thought that the server cannot tell if a request is being sent via browser or script without captcha. I also don't see special authentication headers or parameters (plese let me know if I'm wrong).

I was trying something along these lines

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.oceans14.com.br/rendaVariavel/respostaAjax/gHistoricoPlBovespa.aspx?periodo=completo"
payload = {'periodo': 'completo'}
headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
data = requests.get(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(data.text)
```

This gives the html of the access denial page. Clarification on my misconceptions and a possible working script would be much appreciated!

Comment: In fact, there are many verification methods, such as check params, user-agent, IP, cookies and so on. The suggestion is: try all the header parameters first. If not work, try use the proxy IP (not abroad).

Comment: @Lucas Vieira It seems like they block a request from abroad. Send them an email informing your IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Trock, I tested it and the website requires only the "Referer" and "Cookie" headers. I didn't bother to test all the headers before because I've never came across such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Trock on the comments section, there are multiple verification methods I was not aware of.

This website in particular required the `Referer` and `Cookie` headers for the request to be sent successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).